# How can I execute a block of code one at a time in threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium-webdriver

I have multiple threads and each thread have the below statement

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.print();");
```

I want to execute this statement one at a time in each thread,because when two threads are accessing this statement at the sample time,the output is not as expected.

Here is an example program

```
public class Example {
  static Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @SuppressWarnings("finally")
    public void run() {
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(prof);
      driver.get("http://www.example.com");
      ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.print();");
    }
  });
  static Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @SuppressWarnings("finally")
    public void run() {
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(prof);
      driver.get("http://www.example.com");
      ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.print();");
    }
  });

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Just wrap them in a synchronized block on the same object.

If you want to make sure that one particular line cannot be executed at the same time as another line, just have have them block on a single lock. See: [Intrinsic Locks and Synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

Here is your modified code:

```
public class Example {
  // Create the lock
  static final Object lock = new Object();

  static Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @SuppressWarnings("finally")
    public void run() {
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(prof);
      driver.get("http://www.example.com");

      // synchronize on the lock
      synchronized(lock) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.print();");
      }
    }
  });

  static Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @SuppressWarnings("finally")
    public void run() {
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(prof);
      driver.get("http://www.example.com");

      // synchronize on the lock
      synchronized(lock) {
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.print();");
      }
    }
  });

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
  }
}
```

Comment: This code worked for me     
`synchronized(lock) {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
             ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.print();");
           }`    
Thanks for your help

Comment: @javadb9 It didn't work without the `Thread.sleep()`? Weird, I wonder why.

Comment: Because the printing process(which is outside the scope of program) was taking 1 to 2 seconds to complete and at the time of processing it cannot take new requests,
That's why i had to `Thread.sleep()`

Comment: @javadb9, `sleep()` may have worked for you in this particular case, but in general, using `sleep()` to synchronize threads and processes is a very bad idea.  Bad because, when your code runs in some different environment from the one where you tested it, the thing that you are waiting for in your `sleep()` call may take a different amount of time to complete.

Comment: @jameslarge Thanks for letting me know about that

Answer (score 0):

Do they need to print in a certain order? If so, you may want to use an `ExecutorService` for the background workers.

Call invokeAll() on your ExecutorService, passing in Callable objects. This will return a list of Futures. On your main thread, loop through these Future objects, call get() to get your FireFoxDriver, and then call print() on the driver.

Your Callable body will look like:

```
  WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(prof);
  driver.get("http://www.example.com");
  return driver;
```

Comment: Thanks you for your time